# Flutter integration test to tap on allow button in dialog fail on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, integration-testing

Flutter integration test to tap on allow button in dialog fail on iOS. anyone can help to make this work?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/flutter_driver.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

Future<void> delay([int milliseconds = 250]) async {
  await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
}

void main() {
  group('My App', () {

    FlutterDriver driver;

    // Connect to the Flutter driver before running any tests.
    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    // Close the connection to the driver after the tests have completed.
    tearDownAll(() async {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    }); 



     test('Allow Notification', () async {
        SerializableFinder appBarTitle = find.text("Happy");
        await driver.waitFor(appBarTitle);
        // await delay(3000); // for video capture
        expect(await driver.getText(appBarTitle), isNotEmpty);
     });

  });
}
```

> DriverError: Failed to fulfill WaitFor due to remote error
> Original error: Bad state: The client closed with pending request
> "ext.flutter.driver".   Original stack trace:   #0      new
> Client.withoutJson.
> (package:json_rpc_2/src/client.dart:70:24)   #1
> StackZoneSpecification._run
> (package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:209:15)   #2
> StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.
> (package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:119:48)   #3
> _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)   #4      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)   #5
> _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:163:18)   #6
> Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback
> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:650:39)   #7
> Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:706:37)   #8
> Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:607:9)   #9
> Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)   #10
> Future._asyncComplete.
> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)   #11
> StackZoneSpecification._run
> (package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:209:15)   #12
> StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.
> (package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart:119:48)   #13
> _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)   #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)   #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded
> (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)   #16
> _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)   #17     _microtaskLoop
> (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)   #18
> _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)   #19     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:393:30)   #20     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)   #21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
>
> package:flutter_driver/src/driver/driver.dart 449:7
> FlutterDriver._sendCommand   ===== asynchronous gap
> ===========================   dart:async/zone.dart 1064:19                                  _CustomZone.registerBinaryCallback   dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart 82:23                       _asyncErrorWrapperHelper
> package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart
> Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.   dart:async/zone.dart
> 1126:13                                  _rootRun
> dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19
> _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 1518:10                                  _runZoned   dart:async/zone.dart 1465:12                                  runZoned   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 239:5
> Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks
> package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart 169:33
> Declarer.test..   dart:async/zone.dart 1126:13
> _rootRun   dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19                                  _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 1518:10                                  _runZoned   dart:async/zone.dart 1465:12                                  runZoned   package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart 168:13
> Declarer.test.   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 392:25
> Invoker._onRun....   dart:async/future.dart 176:37
> new Future.
> package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 209:15
> StackZoneSpecification._run
> package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 119:48
> StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.   dart:async/zone.dart
> 1122:38                                  _rootRun
> dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19
> _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 925:7                                    _CustomZone.runGuarded   dart:async/zone.dart 965:23                                   _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.   package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 209:15
> StackZoneSpecification._run
> package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 119:48
> StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.   dart:async/zone.dart
> 1126:13                                  _rootRun
> dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19
> _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 949:23                                   _CustomZone.bindCallback.   dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart 23:15                       Timer._createTimer.
> dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 384:19
> _Timer._runTimers   dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 418:5                      _Timer._handleMessage   dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 174:12                  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage   ===== asynchronous gap ===========================   dart:async/zone.dart 1047:19                                  _CustomZone.registerCallback   dart:async/zone.dart 964:22                                   _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded   dart:async/timer.dart 54:45                                   new Timer   dart:async/timer.dart 91:9
> Timer.run   dart:async/future.dart 174:11
> new Future   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 391:21
> Invoker._onRun...   dart:async/zone.dart 1126:13
> _rootRun   dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19                                  _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 1518:10                                  _runZoned   dart:async/zone.dart 1465:12                                  runZoned   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 378:9
> Invoker._onRun..   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart
> 430:15              Invoker._guardIfGuarded
> package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 377:7
> Invoker._onRun.   package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart 101:24
> Chain.capture.   dart:async/zone.dart 1126:13
> _rootRun   dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19                                  _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 1518:10                                  _runZoned   dart:async/zone.dart 1465:12                                  runZoned   package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart 99:12
> Chain.capture   package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 376:11
> Invoker._onRun
> package:test_api/src/backend/live_test_controller.dart 185:5
> LiveTestController._run
> package:test_api/src/backend/live_test_controller.dart 40:37
> _LiveTest.run   dart:async/future.dart 202:37                                 new Future.microtask.   dart:async/zone.dart 1122:38
> _rootRun   dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19                                  _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 925:7                                    _CustomZone.runGuarded   dart:async/zone.dart 965:23                                   _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.   dart:async/zone.dart 1126:13                                  _rootRun   dart:async/zone.dart 1023:19                                  _CustomZone.run   dart:async/zone.dart 925:7                                    _CustomZone.runGuarded   dart:async/zone.dart 965:23                                   _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.   dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 43:21
> _microtaskLoop   dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 52:5                       _startMicrotaskLoop   dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 393:30                     _Timer._runTimers   dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart 418:5                      _Timer._handleMessage   dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 174:12                  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
>
> 00:31 +1 -1: Some tests failed.
>
> Unhandled exception: Dummy exception to set exit code.
>
> ## 0      _rootHandleUncaughtError. (dart:async/zone.dart:1114:29)
>
> ## 1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
>
> ## 2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
>
> ## 3      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:393:30)
>
> ## 4      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
>
> ## 5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12) Stopping application
>
> instance. Driver tests failed: 255
> [warning] FlutterDriver: waitFor message is taking a long time to complete...

Comment: It would be very helpful to show the exception you're getting.

Comment: ok updated the error

Comment: I read that flutter driver cant interact with ios native components, only android is possible

Comment: Are there any infinite animations running during your test? Have a look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34503#issuecomment-503545683

Comment: there is no animation

Comment: bascially this ios alert dialog popup before any screen came up.

Comment: oh i see, that's an actual native iOS widget. I don't think you can do that, but the best source of information would be Apple's documentation on this subject.

Comment: How about for flutter_test instead of flutter_driver? Can I tap a native iOS widget in flutter_test?

Comment: No, even less so because flutter_test does not have a target operating system - it only runs in the Dart VM. Again, this is an issue with iOS limitations rather than Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my finding will be able to help someone.

I got the error "DriverError: Failed to fulfill Tap due to remote error" and "VMServiceFlutterDriver: tap message is taking a long time to complete.."

In my case, Flutter Driver was not able to find the widgets to test because I was using 'find.byType'.

Once, I have given 'keys' for all widget, and pass to use 'find.byValueKey' instead 'find.byType', the widgets were localized and everything worked perfectly.

Thats my code:

```
void main() {
  group('reversor app integration test', () {
    FlutterDriver driver;

    setUpAll(() async {
      driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
    });

    tearDownAll(() {
      if (driver != null) {
        driver.close();
      }
    });

    // find.byType was the cause for the error 'DriverError: Failed to fulfill Tap due to remote error'
    // Given key for the three below widgets, and after hat using 'find.byValueKey', solved the problem
    var field = find.byValueKey("TextField");
    var btn = find.byValueKey("button");
    var reverse = find.byValueKey("response");

    test('Reversing the string', () async {
      await driver.clearTimeline();
      await driver.tap(field);
      await driver.enterText("Hello222");
      await driver.waitForAbsent(reverse);
      await driver.tap(btn);
      await driver.waitFor(reverse);
      await driver.waitUntilNoTransientCallbacks();
      assert(reverse != null);
    });
  });
}
```